# Find the missing value of the equidistant point

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to come up with an equation, for my own benefit, for calculating the equidistant point between two points in three dimensions, whilst the Y value of the equidistant point has a maximum.

Lets say that I have two points:

```
A:
    x: 0
    y: 10
    z: 0
```

and

```
B:
    x: 10
    y: 600
    z: 10
```

..and the maximum Y value for my point of equidistance (E) is `120`. I understand the equation:

$(E.x - A.x)^2 + (E.y - A.y)^2 + (E.z - A.z)^2 = (E.x - B.x)^2 + (E.y - B.y)^2 + (E.z - B.z)^2$

..yet every time that I factor this equation out, I get stuck...

I am trying to solve for E.x given E.z and E.y, as well as I am trying to solve for E.z given E.x and E.y.

For example, **given E.x and E.y, find E.z:**

I usually say:

let $a = (E.x - A.x)^2 + (E.y - A.y)^2$

..and

let $b = (E.x - B.x)^2 + (E.y - B.y)^2$

We now have:

$a + (E.z - A.z)^2 = b + (E.z - B.z)^2$

I will stop here with all of the amazingly simple parts out of the way, for every time I've gone further, something goes terribly wrong. I have a feeling that the steps to the answer could be very simple, but I'm just throwing a blank.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The set of the points equidistant to $A$ and $B$ is the plane perpendicular to $AB$ that passes by the middle point of $\overline{AB}$. So, any point $(x,y,z)$ satisfying 
$$(x-5)+59(y-305)+(z-5)=0$$
is equidistant to $A$ and $B$, also you need $y\le120$.

---

Let $P(x,y,z)$ be a point, then
\begin{align*}
d(A,P)&=d(B,P)\\
\iff\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-10)^2+(z-0)^2}&=\sqrt{(x-10)^2+(y-600)^2+(z-10)^2}\\
\iff(x-0)^2+(y-10)^2+(z-0)^2&=(x-10)^2+(y-600)^2+(z-10)^2\\
\iff x^2+y^2-20y+100+z^2&=x^2-20x+100+y^2-1200y+600^2+z^2-20z+100\\
\iff (20x-100)+(1180y-359900)+(20z-100)&=0\\
\iff (x-5)+(59y-17995)+(z-5)&=0\\
\iff (x-5)+59(y-305)+(z-5)&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks Mario G, but could you elaborate how you reached this? Where did you get the 59, 305, and 5? I assume that the first 5, the 305, and the last 5 are the x, y, and z values of the middle point of $\overline{AB}$, yet what is the `59` from?

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you so much for the edit Mario! This is just what I wanted!

Comment: Well, alright, I am grateful for your solution, yet you solved my _example_, not my question really... I am trying to re-write your solution in terms of $A$ and $B$ and I am having a very hard time doing so...